# Laravel 4.2 Eloquent only returning 1MB data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, laravel-4

I have a `mediumtext` field in my mySQL database and it only return 1MiB data (a string with length 1048576) with the later part of the string trimmed when I query the database. A common solution I found online is adding this option to `database.php` config file.

```
'options'   => array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE => 16777216
)
```

However, it still only returns 1MiB of data. What else can be the reason causing the problem?

Comment: You should check the mysql configuration in the server and update the settings.

Comment: Have you done php artisan config:cache ?

Comment: From docs: MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE _Maximum buffer size. Defaults to 1 MiB. This constant is not supported when compiled against **mysqlnd**_ Have you checked that?

Comment: Well ... that's what you get for using active-record.

Comment: @SérgioReis Laravel says it is not a valid command. I am maintaining an old project so it is Laravel 4.2. Are you sure it is a valid command?

Comment: @Chay22 How to check? And if yes, how can I change the buffer size?

Comment: @Chay22 Just checked. I am not using mysqlnd.

Comment: According to https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be the problem when making connection to another database. I thought the default settings will be loaded automatically if not set, but it seems it is necessary to set the options even if I am using the same connection profile.

```
//.......... Some other php code ....................
Config::set('database.connections.mysql', array(
         'driver'    => 'mysql',
         'host'      => $db_host,
         'database'  => $db_name,
         'username'  => $db_user,
         'password'  => $db_password,
         'charset'   => 'utf8',
         'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
         'prefix'    => '',
         'options'   => array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE => 16777216 ), //This line was missed
     ));
//.......... Some other php code ....................
```